# How to estimate $SE$ from $95\%$CI, $\alpha $ and $n$?

Tags: probability, statistics

### Background

I am conducting a quantitative synthesis (meta-analysis) that includes previously published data. For the model that I am using, an exact or inflated estimate of SE is acceptable.

### Question

Given a 95% Confidence Interval (measured from mean to upper or lower confidence limit), $\alpha$, and $n$, is it correct to estimate the standard error thus:

$$SE = \frac{CI}{t_{(1-\alpha/2,n)}}$$

?

This is based on the calculation by [Saville, 2003](http://eskes.psychiatry.dal.ca/Files/2003_-_Saville_-_Basic_statistics_and_the_inconsistency_of_m.pdf), but most calculations of CI using the Z score. Unfortunately, $Z=f(SE)$, and I don't think it can be otherwise estimated.

note: this question is a subset of one that has remained unanswered on [stats.stackexchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2917/are-these-formulas-for-transforming-p-lsd-msd-hsd-ci-to-se-as-an-exact-or-in)

Comment: Z=f(SE): Is not Z-score different from the z-statistic ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say yes.

If your sample isn't large enough you should be using $t$ scores to find the confidence interval rather than $z$ scores, anyway.  (Some folks argue that you should *always* use $t$-scores, since the assumption required for using $z$-scores - that you know the population standard deviation $\sigma$ - is rarely satisfied.)  With $t$ scores, and using your notation, the formula for $CI$, half of the width of the confidence interval for a population mean, is known to be

$CI = t_{(1 - \alpha/2,n)} SE$,

so solving that for $SE$ yields the expression you have in your question.

**Update:** Now that Henry has fixed the link, I see that the expression I give is exactly that in Saville's paper.  It's a well-known expression for the confidence interval using $t$-scores, and so, again, I don't see why it would be invalid to use it.  For example, see just about any introductory statistics text, such as Moore, McCabe, and Craig, *Introduction to the Practice of Statistics*, 6th edition, p. 420.